# Question on integration upper bound, area under ellipse

Tags: calculus

[image]

After looking at the picture we are told to find the area enclosed by the total ellipse. See that the first quadrant contains one-fourth of the entire area.

The formula used as the equation of the ellipse is:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
Solving for y:

$$y=\pm\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$$
Then:
$$y=\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$$
Then:
$$\frac{1}{4}A=\int^a_0\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$$

What I don't understand is why a is chosen as the upper bound and not b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548876/find-the-area-of-the-ellipse) you will find the complete method for this calculation. As for your specific question, I understand your confusion. To resolve it, make it a habit to write the variable of integration alongside the integration sign. Your correct step should be:

$$\frac{1}{4}A=\int^a_0\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$$

Notice the $dx$ I added at the end. This makes it clear that the integration is taking place wrt $x$ (*not* $y$, as you must have originally thought). The upper limit for $x$ is clearly $a$ and not $b$.

Comment: So this means since a is alongside the x, under the radical, we use a?

Comment: @Jinzu You _could_ relate to this in such a way. Although a better way is to refer to the diagram you posted above. What is the maximum value of $x$ you can see in the first quadrant?