# integral over given set

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I want to calculate the integral over $$A=\{ (x,y): \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} \leq 1 \}$$

When I solve that equation for y, I get:

$$ y\leq b\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}$$

But how can x be bounded, when I integrate y in this way at first?

Comment: No, you get $-b\sqrt{1-x^2/a^2}\le y\le b\sqrt{1-x^2/a^2}$. And then $1-x^2/a^2\ge 0$, i.e., $x^2\le a^2$ or $-a\le x\le a$. So, the area is $2b\int_{-a}^a\sqrt{1-x^2/a^2}\,dx$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548876/find-the-area-of-the-ellipse/1891110

Comment: I see. You get the upper bound for x  by looking where x is undefined?

Comment: Nowhere in the Question is it clear that you are trying to find the *area*, because "calculate the integral" might mean the integral of an arbitrary integrand over the given elliptical region.  Please reply if a different interpretation than *area* was intended.